# "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals"

Tags: matlab, indexing

I am aware that dozens of threads have been started about this particular error, but none of them actually answer the problem I'm having.

I'm trying to generate a plot of voltage spikes at given intervals using the following code:

```
    V=zeros(1:NN);

    nspace=50;            % Spacing of the spikes in angstroms
    V0=-0.1*eV2J;         % magnitude of the voltage spikes

    for n=10/nspace:NN:nspace
        V(nspace*n)=V0;
    end
```

The variables NN and eV2J are already defined earlier in the code.

Now, here's the problem I'm having that the other threads don't answer.  The indexing error only pops up for certain values of nspace, but not for others.  For example, this block of code executes just fine for...

```
nspace = 20,23,24,27,29,31,32,33,34,36,37,38,40
```

...but the error occurs for all other integer values between 20 and 40, and this seemingly random distribution of acceptable values continues on past 40 as well.  The index generated for all of these values are indeed integers (starting at 10 and incrementing by nspace each loop).

Every thread I've seen for this error states that is occurs when a variable sharaes a name with a built in MATLAB function, or when the index is not a positive real integer or logical.  That is clearly not the case here.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that `10/nspace:NN:nspace` is giving you non-integer values. Maybe try replacing the statement inside your loop with a `disp(nspace*n)` and see what it's putting out. Maybe you can rewrite the index without the division?

Comment: `10/nspace` is clearly a non-integer. Due to finite-precision arithmetic, multiplying it by `nspace` won't always give you an integer index in the loop. If you want to start at 10 and increment by nspace each loop, it would make more sense to do `for n=10:nspace:nspace` and just index by `n`, but that doesn't seem right either. How exactly do you want to populate `V`?

Comment: @JeffE I think you mean `n=10:NN*nspace:nspace^2`

Comment: @JeffE NN represents the size of the total space I have to work with.  V is a voltage lattice, with 100meV spikes appearing at the given interval.  I'm using it to show how this lattice will allow particles below a certain energy threshhold to pass, but resist particles above that energy.  I think doing n=10:nspace:NN should work, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Probably numerical precision issues. Try V(round(nspace*n))=V0;

Comment: @JeffE, replacing "n=10/nspace:NN/nspace" with "n=10:nspace:NN" did the trick, thank you.  I forgot that for loop parameters can be incremented by given values, its not something I've had to do in practice before.  Apparently the professor forgot as well when he wrote the textbook.